# How to calculate the following probability of X being odd?

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution

First let Y follow standard normal distribution - N(0,1). And Let X be the answer you get when you round Y to the nearest integer. Please Calculate P(X is odd).

Comment: Any thoughts?  I suggest doing it numerically...that will quickly tell you the answer which you might then attempt to arrive at directly.

Comment: You can write a rapidly-converging series for the answer, by taking the expectation of  the Fourier series of a square wave with respect to $N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

$2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(0.5 + 2k \leq Y \leq 1.5+2k)$

$= 2 \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left [ \Phi(1.5 + 2k) - \Phi(0.5 + 2k) \right ]$

Comment: The probability formula sounds good to me! But I wonder what does the times 2 mean at front?

Comment: to account for odd negative integers.

Comment: got it! thank you